# Is there a way to drop index by fields names

Tags: postgresql

In some of the migrations, I have indexes created without explicit name set. Which usually provoke the automatic (by PostgreSQL engine) index name generation.

I'm looking a way to drop indexes by specific field names instead of index name.

There seems to be a way to get the list of indexes:

```
select *
from pg_indexes
where tablename = 'myTable'
```

Any recommendations for elegant way to "programmatically" DROP INDEX having only specific field or multiple field names?

Comment: What if a column appears in more than one index? What is with indexes on expressions?

Comment: I'm not asking here to delete indexes that include fieldName + all other fields, but it could be interesting too.